# Issues in installation of rasa-x to office laptop

Tags: installation, vpn, firewall, rasa-x

I tried below command to install rasa-x on my office laptop:

```
python -m pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

but it gave me below error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
Collecting rasa-x
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /rasa-packages/8789/rasa-x/rasa_x-0.31.0-py3-none-any.whl?Signature=hPxskutJmwG%2BUsEc8KuXK5JZ1%2B8P2FGKtUzD8dQGgTlKilNJyNJJO5WrCb1ON2E50k8qjLDHGkjx1XWLjxMfsJUD5wrekFPyeSPSadIgk21lNHzi7NgPi0r9NAl4t6pNln%2FPTtabxzY358ZYiov4wXAEAGyi8BxkAQZ73mnSSK4NE%2FlNnq1%2FVuZknUI3c3NBIbHZBgFExsx33kVpXfD4uGH%2FSdKWV0b9UJBnAPG3UM9OQ8EdJSB7ZYNPup1KEJuYvtrWWh7VrtvzhrmRy48RylbJZN9MlPcb02uoxDQ8uCOLGxyPUuk9sn0C8IYH6mdnUK5ODjQmA3DVxKz5l%2BuN6w%3D%3D&GoogleAccessId=pypi-storage%40pypi-190908.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1595317457
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /rasa-packages/8789/rasa-x/rasa_x-0.31.0-py3-none-any.whl?Signature=hPxskutJmwG%2BUsEc8KuXK5JZ1%2B8P2FGKtUzD8dQGgTlKilNJyNJJO5WrCb1ON2E50k8qjLDHGkjx1XWLjxMfsJUD5wrekFPyeSPSadIgk21lNHzi7NgPi0r9NAl4t6pNln%2FPTtabxzY358ZYiov4wXAEAGyi8BxkAQZ73mnSSK4NE%2FlNnq1%2FVuZknUI3c3NBIbHZBgFExsx33kVpXfD4uGH%2FSdKWV0b9UJBnAPG3UM9OQ8EdJSB7ZYNPup1KEJuYvtrWWh7VrtvzhrmRy48RylbJZN9MlPcb02uoxDQ8uCOLGxyPUuk9sn0C8IYH6mdnUK5ODjQmA3DVxKz5l%2BuN6w%3D%3D&GoogleAccessId=pypi-storage%40pypi-190908.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1595317457
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /rasa-packages/8789/rasa-x/rasa_x-0.31.0-py3-none-any.whl?Signature=hPxskutJmwG%2BUsEc8KuXK5JZ1%2B8P2FGKtUzD8dQGgTlKilNJyNJJO5WrCb1ON2E50k8qjLDHGkjx1XWLjxMfsJUD5wrekFPyeSPSadIgk21lNHzi7NgPi0r9NAl4t6pNln%2FPTtabxzY358ZYiov4wXAEAGyi8BxkAQZ73mnSSK4NE%2FlNnq1%2FVuZknUI3c3NBIbHZBgFExsx33kVpXfD4uGH%2FSdKWV0b9UJBnAPG3UM9OQ8EdJSB7ZYNPup1KEJuYvtrWWh7VrtvzhrmRy48RylbJZN9MlPcb02uoxDQ8uCOLGxyPUuk9sn0C8IYH6mdnUK5ODjQmA3DVxKz5l%2BuN6w%3D%3D&GoogleAccessId=pypi-storage%40pypi-190908.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1595317457
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /rasa-packages/8789/rasa-x/rasa_x-0.31.0-py3-none-any.whl?Signature=hPxskutJmwG%2BUsEc8KuXK5JZ1%2B8P2FGKtUzD8dQGgTlKilNJyNJJO5WrCb1ON2E50k8qjLDHGkjx1XWLjxMfsJUD5wrekFPyeSPSadIgk21lNHzi7NgPi0r9NAl4t6pNln%2FPTtabxzY358ZYiov4wXAEAGyi8BxkAQZ73mnSSK4NE%2FlNnq1%2FVuZknUI3c3NBIbHZBgFExsx33kVpXfD4uGH%2FSdKWV0b9UJBnAPG3UM9OQ8EdJSB7ZYNPup1KEJuYvtrWWh7VrtvzhrmRy48RylbJZN9MlPcb02uoxDQ8uCOLGxyPUuk9sn0C8IYH6mdnUK5ODjQmA3DVxKz5l%2BuN6w%3D%3D&GoogleAccessId=pypi-storage%40pypi-190908.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1595317457
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /rasa-packages/8789/rasa-x/rasa_x-0.31.0-py3-none-any.whl?Signature=hPxskutJmwG%2BUsEc8KuXK5JZ1%2B8P2FGKtUzD8dQGgTlKilNJyNJJO5WrCb1ON2E50k8qjLDHGkjx1XWLjxMfsJUD5wrekFPyeSPSadIgk21lNHzi7NgPi0r9NAl4t6pNln%2FPTtabxzY358ZYiov4wXAEAGyi8BxkAQZ73mnSSK4NE%2FlNnq1%2FVuZknUI3c3NBIbHZBgFExsx33kVpXfD4uGH%2FSdKWV0b9UJBnAPG3UM9OQ8EdJSB7ZYNPup1KEJuYvtrWWh7VrtvzhrmRy48RylbJZN9MlPcb02uoxDQ8uCOLGxyPUuk9sn0C8IYH6mdnUK5ODjQmA3DVxKz5l%2BuN6w%3D%3D&GoogleAccessId=pypi-storage%40pypi-190908.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1595317457
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rasa-packages/8789/rasa-x/rasa_x-0.31.0-py3-none-any.whl?Signature=hPxskutJmwG%2BUsEc8KuXK5JZ1%2B8P2FGKtUzD8dQGgTlKilNJyNJJO5WrCb1ON2E50k8qjLDHGkjx1XWLjxMfsJUD5wrekFPyeSPSadIgk21lNHzi7NgPi0r9NAl4t6pNln%2FPTtabxzY358ZYiov4wXAEAGyi8BxkAQZ73mnSSK4NE%2FlNnq1%2FVuZknUI3c3NBIbHZBgFExsx33kVpXfD4uGH%2FSdKWV0b9UJBnAPG3UM9OQ8EdJSB7ZYNPup1KEJuYvtrWWh7VrtvzhrmRy48RylbJZN9MlPcb02uoxDQ8uCOLGxyPUuk9sn0C8IYH6mdnUK5ODjQmA3DVxKz5l%2BuN6w%3D%3D&GoogleAccessId=pypi-storage%40pypi-190908.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1595317457 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

But I thought This can happen if a corporate proxy is not allowing access to pypi.org.” I further tried to install rasa-x with below command:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org rasa-x
```

But still I am getting below error:

```
Collecting rasa-x
  Using cached rasa-x-0.0.2.tar.gz (1.4 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\agupt80\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wnjmorry\\rasa-x\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\agupt80\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wnjmorry\\rasa-x\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2'
         cwd: C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wnjmorry\rasa-x\
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2\rasa_x.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2\rasa_x.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2\rasa_x.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2\rasa_x.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2\rasa_x.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2\rasa_x.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-ghomfeg2\rasa_x.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\agupt80\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wnjmorry\rasa-x\setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError('Please use `pip install rasa-x -i https://pypi.rasa.com/simple` instead to install the rasa-x package')
    RuntimeError: Please use `pip install rasa-x -i https://pypi.rasa.com/simple` instead to install the rasa-x package
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks & Regards
Amit Gupta

Answer (score 0):

This should work. give a shot.

```
“pip install rasa-x -i https://pypi.rasa.com/simple --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.rasa.com --trusted-host storage.googleapis.com --proxy=proxy.example.com”
```